# Error with signature when creating an outbound shipment on Amazon MWS API

Tags: node.js, amazon-mws

I'm trying to create an outbound fulfillment (CreateFulfillmentOrder) on the Amazon MWS API. I'm using the node.js package mws-api to make the request, which I have modified myself since it didn't support this operation correctly. In any case, this is the exact request that I'm sending to the API (with sensitive information changed):

```
{ 
 uri: 'https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01',
 method: 'POST',
 headers:
  { Host: 'mws.amazonservices.co.uk',
    'User-Agent': 'mws-api/0.1.0 (Language=JavaScript)',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content-length': 1095 },
 body: 'SellerFulfillmentOrderId=403-9883411-3564317&ShippingSpeedCategory=Standard&DisplayableOrderId=403-9883411-3564317&DisplayableOrderDateTime=2013-12-29&DisplayableOrderComment=Order&NotificationEmailList.member.1=3yv4at7rtl3blsy%40marketplace.amazon.co.uk&DestinationAddress.Name=Amazon%20Taro&DestinationAddress.Line1=COMPANY%NAME&DestinationAddress.City=GORING&DestinationAddress.StateOrProvinceCode=Oxon&DestinationAddress.PostalCode=RG8%209AQ&DestinationAddress.CountryCode=GB&DestinationAddress.PhoneNumber=01575375219&Items.member.1.DisplayableComment=item&Items.member.1.GiftMessage=gift&Items.member.1.PerUnitDeclaredValue.Value=4.29&Items.member.1.PerUnitDeclaredValue.CurrencyCode=GBP&Items.member.1.Quantity=1&Items.member.1.SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId=CW0298&Items.member.1.SellerSKU=CW0298&Action=CreateFulfillmentOrder&Version=2010-10-01&Timestamp=2017-04-12T14%3A39%3A22.707Z&AWSAccessKeyId=LYIAJ83AORVSI6WLBTQA&SellerId=7RVB74LQNDFDB1&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Signature=nlB5UTDUXexkurlsc7e%2F4tqLO8vcMRy4X%6Oa0rPIapZN8%3D' }
```

But all I'm getting in response is this error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

I don't there's any problem with the signature, it has worked correctly while doing other operations. I think that's just the error Amazon gives you when something's wrong on the request, but I cannot find the problem. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, that error message is only returned when the signature is actually wrong. While other MWS error messages have been misleading, I've never seen a case where it was complaining about a signature and the resolution was something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Amazon Host **mws.amazonaws.com**.

Ex:

```
    { 
     uri: 'https://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01',
     method: 'POST',
     headers:
      { Host: 'mws.amazonaws.com',
            'User-Agent': 'mws-api/0.1.0 (Language=JavaScript)',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content-length': 1095 
       },
       body:'SellerFulfillmentOrderId=403-9883411-3564317&ShippingSpeedCategory=Standard&DisplayableOrderId=403-9883411-3564317&DisplayableOrderDateTime=2013-12-29&DisplayableOrderComment=Order&NotificationEmailList.member.1=3yv4at7rtl3blsy%40marketplace.amazon.co.uk&DestinationAddress.Name=Amazon%20Taro&DestinationAddress.Line1=COMPANY%NAME&DestinationAddress.City=GORING&DestinationAddress.StateOrProvinceCode=Oxon&DestinationAddress.PostalCode=RG8%209AQ&DestinationAddress.CountryCode=GB&DestinationAddress.PhoneNumber=01575375219&Items.member.1.DisplayableComment=item&Items.member.1.GiftMessage=gift&Items.member.1.PerUnitDeclaredValue.Value=4.29&Items.member.1.PerUnitDeclaredValue.CurrencyCode=GBP&Items.member.1.Quantity=1&Items.member.1.SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId=CW0298&Items.member.1.SellerSKU=CW0298&Action=CreateFulfillmentOrder&Version=2010-10-01&Timestamp=2017-04-12T14%3A39%3A22.707Z&AWSAccessKeyId=LYIAJ83AORVSI6WLBTQA&SellerId=7RVB74LQNDFDB1&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Signature=nlB5UTDUXexkurlsc7e%2F4tqLO8vcMRy4X%6Oa0rPIapZN8%3D' 
    }
```

This may help you.